# Why this Unzip shell script behaves differently when environment change Dev to Prod?

Tags: shell, apache-spark, unix, hadoop2

```
output_path=s3://output
unziped_dir=s3://2019-01-03
files=`hadoop fs -ls $output_path/ | awk '{print $NF}' | grep .gz$ | tr '\n' ' '`;
for f in $files
do   
echo "available files are: $f"
filename=$(hadoop fs -ls $f | awk -F '/' '{print $NF}' | head -1)
hdfs dfs -cat $f | gzip -d | hdfs dfs -put - $unziped_dir"/"${filename%.*}
echo "unziped file names: ${filename%.*}"
done
```

Output:

> Dev:

```
available files are: s3://2019-01-03/File_2019-01-03.CSV.gz
unziped file names: File_2019-01-03.CSV
available files are: s3://2019-01-03/Data_2019-01-03.CSV.gz
unziped file names: Data_2019-01-03.CSV
available files are: s3://2019-01-03/Output_2019-01-03.CSV.gz
unziped file names: Output_2019-01-03.CSV
```

> Prod:

```
available files are: s3://2019-01-03/File_2019-01-03.CSV.gz s3://2019-01-03/Data_2019-01-03.CSV.gz s3://2019-01-03/Output_2019-01-03.CSV.gz 
unziped file names:
```

I am trying to look into a directory and identify the .gz files and iterate them to unzip the all .gz files and store into a different directory. But when am running this script in **EMR dev cluster**, its works fine. But in prod cluster its not. Please find the behavior of the script above.

Comment: If you used good practices for reading line-by-line input (as given in [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)) rather than all the unquoted expansions for word-splitting, these issues would be avoided outright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with the word splitting in `for f in $files`. Normally the shell should split the value `$files` at the spaces as it does on Dev.
On Dev `f` is set to one of the three words from `$files` in every cycle of the `for` loop, on Prod `f` gets the complete value of `$files` including spaces.

Do you set variable `IFS` somewhere?

If the problem is not in other parts of your script you should be able to reproduce the problem with a reduced script:

```
files="foo bar baz"
for f in $files
do   
  echo "available files are: $f"
done
```

If this minimal script doesn't show a difference the problem is in other parts of your script.

To see if the value of `IFS` is different on Dev and Prod you can add this to the minimal script or to your original script just before the `for` loop:

```
# To see if IFS is different. With the default value (space, tab, newline) the output should be
# 0000000   I   F   S   =   #      \t  \n   #  \n
# 0000012
echo "IFS=#${IFS}#" | od -c
```

If you see a difference in the value of `IFS` you have to find out where `IFS` is modified.

BTW: Normally you can omit `| tr '\n' ' '` after the grep command. The shell should accept `\n` as word splitting character when processing `for f in $files`. If not, this is probably related to the source of your problem.

**Edit:** There is a better solution to process the data line by line, see
https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor and
https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

You should use a `while read`... instead of `for`...

Modified script (untested)

```
output_path=s3://output
unziped_dir=s3://2019-01-03

hadoop fs -ls "$output_path"/ | awk '{print $NF}' | grep .gz$ | while IFS= read -r f
do   
    echo "available files are: $f"
    filename=$(hadoop fs -ls "$f" | awk -F '/' '{print $NF}' | head -1)
    hdfs dfs -cat "$f" | gzip -d | hdfs dfs -put - "${unziped_dir}/${filename%.*}"
    echo "unziped file names: ${filename%.*}"
done
```

Comment: It's worth noting that relying on word splitting (or failing to quote adequately to prevent *unintended* word splitting) is strongly advised against in the bash community, being probably the cause of more of the problems listed in [BashPitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) than any other single practice.